# BASH function for escaping spaces in filenames before opening them

Tags: bash, terminal

I've been trying to write a function for my bash profile for quite some time now.
The problem I'm trying to overcome is I'm usually provided with file paths that include spaces and it's a pain having to go through and escape all the spaces before I try to open it up in terminal.

e.g.
File -> /Volumes/Company/Illustrators/Website Front Page Design.ai

What I'm trying to end up with is '/Volumes/Company/Illustrators/Website\ Front\ Page\ Design.ai' being opened from my terminal.

So far I've managed to escape the spaces out, but I then get the error "The file ..... does not exist."

My code so far is

```
function opn { open "${1// /\\ }";}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there something wrong about `open "my file name"` or `open "$filename"`?

Comment: In general, escaping spaces is Doing It Wrong. If you quote correctly, you don't need literal escapes in your data.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, the `function` keyword is non-POSIX syntax. Consider instead writing your functions as `opn() { open "$@"; }`, with no leading `function`, to be compatible with a wider range of shells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing to understand is the difference between *syntax* and *literal data*.

When done correctly, escaping is **syntax**: It's read and discarded by the shell. That is, when you run

```
open "File With Spaces"
```

or

```
open File\ With\ Spaces
```

or even

```
open File" "With\ Spaces
```

...the quoting and escaping is parsed and removed by the shell, and the actual operating system call that gets executed is this:

```
execv("/usr/bin/open", "open", "File With Spaces")
```

Note that there aren't any backslashes (or literal quotes) in that syscall's arguments! If you put **literal** backslashes in your data, then you cause this to be run:

```
/* this is C syntax, so "\\" is a single-character backslash literal */
execv("/usr/bin/open", "open", "File\\ With\\ Spaces")
```

...and unless there's a file with backslashes in its name, that just doesn't work, giving the "file does not exist" error you report.

---

So -- just call open with your name in quotes:

```
open "$1"
```

...there's no need for an `opn` wrappper.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, not only did your solution work, but it obviously negated the need to create a separate function entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are problematic in filenames because they're part of `bash`'s default `IFS` (Internal Field Separator), which is used to separate tokens in a command line. That means that by default, when you use `command an argument with spaces`, the command will receive 4 arguments rather than 1 containing spaces.

I'm guessing you called your `opn` function in the same way, thus resulting in only the first part of your path as `$1`.

Hopefully, the fix is easy : enclose your path in quotes so that `bash` does not interpret the spaces. By using this, the need for your `opn` function disappears : `open "/Volumes/Company/Illustrators/Website Front Page Design.ai"` should work just fine.

Comment: You've escaped the spaces twice: once with the backslash, and once with the enclosing quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm talking about OP's `opn` function