# I want to embed a single quote in a string

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Usually, in order to embed a quotation mark in a string, `\` (backslash) is used.

Does a backslash have a different meaning in a Bash script?

My code below isn't working: the quotation mark wasn't included, and the following errors were reported:

```
recursive_merge.sh: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
recursive_merge.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have no explanation. Line 14 doesn't even exist.

```
 #!/bin/bash
#############this file should be in the directory directly upper than p0x. sphnum.txt should also be at the same directory
for i in 02 03 04 05 06 07 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 20 21 22 23 24 25; do
 x=$(grep $i sphnum.txt |cut -c5-6)
 y=$(grep $i sphnum.txt |cut -c8-9)
 z=$(echo '\''$i'.ala.r'$x'.sph '$i'.ala.r'$y'.sph\'')
 w=$(echo $i'.ala.r'$x'r'$y'.sph')
 echo $z
 echo $w
 cd p$i/spheres.10_2_75/sph/
 /project/Biogroup/Software/Docking/MergeSpheres.pl -s $z -o $w -n 500 &
 cd ../../../
done
```

Comment: Use [\[ shellcheck \]](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: @tripleee: While the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) is generally related, neither it nor its answers address _embedding_ single quotes inside (single-quoted) strings or producing _stand-alone_ single-quote literals, which is the focus of _this_ question.

Comment: @mklement0 Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27701642/874188 suggests using double quotes around the single quotes when you want a literal single quote.  But I am fine with leaving this question open as well.  (For context, for future readers, I previously marked this as a duplicate, but it was reverted.)

Comment: You should be using `echo "$variable"` with double quotes throughout; your diagnostics are off because the lack of quoting effectively makes the shell evaluate the variable again -- you basically don't see what you're doing.  Again, the [duplicate I proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) covers this in much more detail.

Comment: And of course, the [useless use of `echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) probably throws you off some more (unless the purpose of that is to experiment with how command substitution complicates matters even further).

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks; all good points; I've added a preamble to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings though I'll leave it to the community to decide now, since my duplicate already got rejected once.

Comment: Though I'm guessing this is really properly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572630/bash-function-for-escaping-spaces-in-filenames-before-opening-them/38572764#38572764 -- if you are trying to put a literal quote but the file name you are trying to access does not actually contain a literal quote, you need to understand at what level the quotes are useful and relevant, and how the shell peels them off.

Comment: @triplee: I agree that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings comes closest as a duplicate; to me this answer still has a distinct angle, though it's hard to address all its layers without losing focus. No duplicate candidate juxtaposes all approaches to embedding a single quote, as far as I can tell (which is admittedly the thing _I_ chose to focus on). If you feel strong enough about one of your duplicate candidates, please go ahead.

Comment: My strongest suspicion is in the last comment; the OP is mistaken, and doesn't actually need a literal single quote. But this is qualified guesswork, so I'm simply offering this for the OP to decide.

Comment: `foo="'a b'"; echo $foo` is not the same as `echo 'a b'`, if that is why you are trying to put single quotes in the value. The former passes two arguments, `'a` and `b'` to `echo`, while the latter passes a single argument `a b`.

Comment: Thanks dudes!  It helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) points out in comments on the question, the **best approach in this particular scenario is to use a *double-quoted* string, in which you can embed both variable references (e.g., `$i`) and single quotes *as-is***; e.g.:  `z="'$i.ala.r$x.sph $i .ala.r$y.sph'"`

**This answer focuses on the various approaches to producing / embedding literal `'` chars. in strings**, starting with the OP's misconception.</sup>

Your use of `'\''` suggests that you're confused by the workaround that is commonly used to "embed" a single quote in an *overall single-quoted string*, which is *not* what your code does on the `z=...` line, because it *starts* with `'\''`.

If we simplify your command, we get:

```
echo '\''$i
```

which is a *syntax* error, because to Bash the single quotes are *unbalanced*, because `'\'` *by itself* is considered a complete single-quoted string containing literal `\`, followed by the *opening* `'` of a *second* single-quoted string, which is never *closed*.

<sup>Again it's worth noting that `"'$i"` is the best solution to this specific problem: the `'` can be embedded as-is, and including variable reference `$i` inside the double-quoted string protects its value from potentially unwanted [word-splitting and filename expansion (globbing)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).</sup>

**POSIX-like shells provide NO way to embed single quotes inside a single-quoted string** - not even with escaping. Hence, the `\` in `'\'` is simply treated as a literal (see below for a workaround).

The rest of this answer shows all **approaches to producing a literal `'`, both inside and outside quoted strings**.

---

To create a single quotation mark ***outside* of a quoted string**, simply use `\'`:

```
$ echo I am 6\' tall.
I am 6' tall.
```

This quotes (escapes) the individual `'` character only, using `\`.
But note that tokens placed outside the context of a single- or double-quoted string on a command line are subject to [word-splitting and filename expansion (globbing)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

---

To use a single quote **inside a *double-quoted* string**, use it as-is (no escaping needed):

```
$ echo "I am 6' tall."
I am 6' tall.
```

This is the best choice if you also want to embed variable references (e.g., `$i`) or commands (via command substitutions, `$(...)`) in your string (you can suppress interpolation by escaping `$` as `\$`).

---

To use a single quote **inside a *single-quoted* string** (in which *no* interpolations (expansions) are performed by design), you must use a *workaround*:

```
$ echo 'I am 6'\'' tall.'
I am 6' tall.
```

The workaround is necessitated by single-quoted strings not supporting embedded single quotes *at all*; the `'\''` part only makes sense "inside" a single-quoted string in that:

- the leading `'` terminates the single-quoted string *so far*
- the `\'` then produces a `'` literal individually escaped with `\` *outside* the context of a quoted string.
- the trailing `'` then "restarts" the remainder of the single-quoted string.

In other words: While you cannot directly embed a single quote, you can break the single-quoted string into multiple pieces, insert individually `\`-escaped `'` instances *outside* the single-quoted string as needed, and let Bash's string concatenation (which automatically joins directly adjacent string) piece it all back together to form a single string.

---

[chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out in a comment that you can **alternatively use a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) with a *quoted* opening delimiter**, which acts like a *single-quoted* string while allowing embedding of `'` chars:

```
read -r var <<'EOF' # quoted delimiter -> like a '...' string, but ' can be embedded
I am 6' tall.
EOF
```

With an ***unquoted* opening delimiter**, the here-document acts like a *double-quoted* string, which, just like the latter, also allows embedding `'`, while also supporting expansions:

```
read -r var <<EOF # unquoted delimiter -> like a "..." string
$USER is 6' tall.
EOF
```

---

Finally, **if remaining POSIX-compliant is not a must**, you can use an **[ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) string, which allows embedding single quotes with `\'`**;
note that such strings interpret control-character escape sequences such as `\n`, but otherwise, like a normal single-quoted string, do not perform interpolation of variable references or command substitutions:

```
$ echo $'I am 6\' tall.'
I am 6' tall.
```

Comment: Thanks, @chepner. I've added your suggestion to the answer.